# How to handle large QueryResults in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

If I try to iterate trough a QueryResult with a lot of relations, my foreach loop needs a lot of time.

```
    /** @var Product $productItem */
    foreach ($products as $productItem) {
        print($productItem->getTitle());
    }
```

How can I do it the fast way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate relations in every model with @lazy which will save you alot of time. After adding @lazy annoation you have to clear the cache in the install tool or reinstall the extension to take effect.